# How to update sql table where id is in array codeigniter?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, sql-server, codeigniter

I have array id like this,

```
Array ( [0] => 1013 [1] => 1012 [2] => 1011 [3] => 1010 )
```

I want to update my table user by those id,
here my controller code

```
public function index()
{
    $id = $this->input->post('check_list');
    print_r($id); // just try to check output value
    $this->template->load('v_t','v_e', $data);
}
```

thanks.

Comment: What did you achieve so far?

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov thanks for reply, my problem is solved :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use where_in like below

```
$this->db->where_in("id", $ids);
$this->db->update("tableName", $data);
```

Change above code with your table name and column names.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for all, I just found my answer, here my controller code for update sql by array id

```
public function update()
{
    $this->load->database();

    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $checkbox) {
        $data = array(
                'STATS' => 'A');
        $this->db->where('ID', $checkbox);
        $this->db->update('USERS', $data);

    }
```